# How to connect by role in ActiveMQ Artemis via JMX?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I have a Java application using JavaFX. I don't understand how to connect by role. So that each role has its own rights to proofread, etc. I know how to add a role to ActiveMQ, but my application seems to connect to the main role without choosing.

Here is what the connection frame looks like:
[image]

```java
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl) {

    QueueConnection connection = null;
    try {
        QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
        connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
        connection.start();
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(BuildGet.JMX_URL));

        return connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

How to connect by roles?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually connect "by role." You connect with a username and a password.

Roles are how users are organized *on the broker*. You can have one or more users in a given role and then permissions are granted to that role as a whole. This makes it easier to organize users and configure security.

Keep in mind that the security configuration for messaging users (e.g. those using JMS) is separate from management users (e.g. those using JMX). The former is done via `security-settings` in `broker.xml` and the latter is done via `authorisation` in `management.xml`.

In your case, you can supply credentials for the JMX connection like so:

```java
         HashMap env = new HashMap();
         String[] creds = {"myUser", "myPassword"};
         env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);

         JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(BuildGet.JMX_URL), env);
```

It's important to note that your `connectBroker` method is **leaking** a JMS connection every time it is invoked. This is because you create a JMS connection, but you don't close it or return it from the method. I recommend removing the JMS connection from that method entirely as it servers no real purpose.

Comment: connectBroker method uses JMS connection by broker url. If there is any way to make a connection to the broker url via JMX, then I will be very grateful)

Comment: You asked how to connect to the broker with **JMX**, not JMS. JMX and JMS use different APIs and URLs to connect. You can't use one for the other. That makes no sense.